# css item width percent in fixed position div?

Tags: html, fixed, css

I'm trying to have an image inside of a `position:fixed` div respond to the width of the browser.

The `img` is inside of a 100% width `div` with a margin of 100px on both sides, and those are both inside of a `div` with a `max-width` of 750px, all inside of a div that is fixed position.

Once the browser is resized to something less than 750px, normally, the image would begin sizing down automatically. It seems that since it's in a fixed position that it is just getting cut off. Is there a way around this, with the div still remaining fixed?

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to give the image element a percentage width e.g. `img{width:100%;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/jg6va/

Comment: Excellent. I thought I had done that already, but I had only set the `li` to 100%. Thanks.